# quadro K5100M dual 4k outputs

Tags: nvidia-quadro

i recently bought a laptop with NVIDIA Quadro K5100M inside
it comes with two displayports and one hdmi.

is it possible for that GPU to output 2x4K (3840x2160) at 50hz at the same time ?
in desktop extended mode , not in clone mode ?
with the two display ports or 1 displayport + 1 HDMI

For a customer work i need the computer to display an image or video of 7680x2160 px.
it's in europe so i have to be at 50hz.

Thanks for your help

Kim

Answer (score 0):

Based on its specifications:

> the NVIDIA Quadro K5100M for gaming with highest details at
>   resolutions up to, and including, 1680x1050.and including, 1680x1050.

Based on the specifications I found, it cannot even run a single display at 3840x2160, let alone 2 displays both at 50 Hz.

[NVIDIA Quadro K5100M](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2425/quadro-k5100m)